# Is there an operator such that the spectrum of all its nontrivial commutants is strictly continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

**Definition** : let $A \in B(H)$, then its spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is the set of all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $A - \lambda I$ is not bijective. It [decomposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_%28functional_analysis%29) as follows:
 - *Point spectrum*: $\sigma_{p}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \text{ not injective}   \}$
 - *Continuous spectrum*: $\sigma_{c}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{ injective with a dense nonclosed range}   \}$
 - *Residual spectrum*: $\sigma_{r}(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : A - \lambda I \ \text{ injective with a nondense range}   \}$

**Definition** : let $\mathcal{S}$ be a subset of $B(H)$, its **commutant** $\mathcal{S}'$  is $ \{A \in B(H) : AB=BA \ , \ \forall B \in \mathcal{S}  \} $.

> Is there an operator $T \in B(H)$ such that if $\mathbb{C} I \not\ni A \in \{ T \}'$ then $\sigma(A) = \sigma_{c}(A)$ ?

**Bonus question** : what is the set of all such operators ?

Comment: Excluding @Landscape's trivial example, let $p(T)$ be any polynomial in $T$ with roots in point spectrum of $T$. Then $0$ is in the point spectrum of $p(T)$. This shows that $T$ you want must have empty point spectrum.

Comment: Surely if $k$ is a large scalar then $0$ is not in the spectrum of $T+kI$?

Comment: You're right @ChrisEagle, let me think, I have to improve the question.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: I found the improvement and I have posted it.